# Updating products in a mysqli database using PHP

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Trying to update 1 row at a time using php.

I want to enable users to update products they have already added to a database, I have a simple form with the relevant fields:

```
 <fieldset><legend><span> Update a product in the database! </span></legend>

        <form  id ="productsform" method="post" onsubmit="return false;" enctype="multipart/form-data">


        <label> Product name:               <input  type="text"     id="name"           name="name"/>           </label>

        <label> Product quantity:           <input  type="number"   id="quantity"       name="quantity"/>       </label>

        <label> Product description:        <input  type="text"     id="description"    name="description"/>    </label>

        <label> Product price:              <input  type="text"     id="price"          name="price"/>          </label>

        </br>

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="button" class="reg" value="Update Product">

        <div id="update"></div>

            </form>
```

I am using ajax which is working correctly according the console, but im struggling with the php side of updating the rows:

```
<?php

include("dbase/config_database.php");

$id = $_POST["id"];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$price = $_POST['price'];

$query = "UPDATE products SET name = '{$name}', quantity = '{$quantity}', description = '{$description}', price = '{$price}' 
WHERE id = {$id}";

mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

?>
```

Here is the initial file I use to add the products to the database:

```
<?php
include("dbase/config_database.php");

//Stores all information passed through AJAX into the query
$name = $_POST['name'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$price = $_POST['price'];


//Adds information to database
$query = "INSERT INTO products (name, quantity, description, price) VALUES ('$name','$quantity','$description','$price')";
//Runs the query
$result = $mysqli->query($query) OR die("Failed query $query");
echo $mysqli->error."<p>";

echo "Product Added";

$querynew = ("SELECT id as 'collectid' from products WHERE name = '$name'and quantity = '$quantity'and description ='$description'and price = '$price'");
$resultnew = $mysqli->query($querynew) OR die("Failed query $querynew");

while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultnew)){
    $productid = $info['collectid'];
}

$image = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$type = $_FILES['file1']['type'];
$size = $_FILES['file1']['size'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];

$imgpath = "images/".$productid.".jpg";

// Run the move_uploaded_file() function here
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $imgpath);
// Evaluate the value returned from the function if needed

$querytwo = ("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = '$name' and quantity = '$quantity' and description = '$description' and price = '$price'");
$resulttwo = $mysqli ->query($querytwo) OR die ("Failed query $querynew");

$info = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulttwo)){
    $product = array("id" => $row ['id'],
        "name" => $row ['name'],
        "quantity" => $row ['quantity'],
        "description" => $row ['description'],
        "price" => $row ['price'],

);

    array_push($info,$product);
}

$json_output = json_encode($info);
echo $json_output;
?>
```

Any help is much appreciated! I have messed around with the update php because im sure the problem is in there but cant find it.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: where this is coming from? `$_POST["id"];`

Comment: I get undefined index: id on line 5 in the updateSQL.php

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the `$_POST["id"]` from the form,because there is no input element with name `id`.

when you get all the data from the table then put the `id` in the form as a hidden field

like

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>">
```

then after submitting the form you'll get the `id` value in `$_POST['id']`

Always try to debug your code thoroughly try to print the query then you can easily know what is happening actually.All the best